# spring-cloud-gateway path route predicate don't accept "/"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a custom gateway filter that use the route written in application.yml,
When I want to change the route predicate from ***/test/myTest*** to ***/public*** the request return 404 it seemes like the "/" is not reconized because I tried to change /test-myTest to /public and it's work.

Any idea please how can I use a predicate with this format /name/name/**

this is my application.yml :

```
myTest-gateway:
default-uri: https://app
apps:
  /test/myTest: mymicroservice-name
spring:
  cloud:
   gateway:
     enabled: false
     x-forwarded:
      proto-enabled: false 
     routes:
      - id: appsPrefixPathPublic
         uri: ${myTest-gateway.default-uri}
         predicates:
           - AppPath=/test/myTest
         filters:
          - StripPrefix=1
          - PrefixPath=/public
```

this is the error that I got it :

> No content
>
> < 404 NOT_FOUND Not Found < Content-Type: [application/json] <
> Content-Length: [147]
>
> {"timestamp":"2020-08-26T15:44:12.023+0000","path":"/test/myTest/whatever","status":404,"error":"Not
> Found","message":null,"requestId":"e7baeeeb-6"}
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404
> NOT_FOUND>

Comment: Note that you should protect URLs with backticks; it seems that your question likely isn't displaying properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-stripprefix-gatewayfilter-factory) :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: nameRoot
        uri: https://nameservice
        predicates:
        - Path=/name/**
        filters:
        - StripPrefix=2
```

When a request is made through the gateway to `/name/blue/red`, the request made to `nameservice` looks like `nameservice/red`.

You should change 1 to 2.